# Animated progress bar with counter

Tags: html, css, css-animations

Please, can anyone help me to create an animated progress bar with counter like the image below

[Animated progress bar with counter on the right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TRCTr.png)

I have searched in google and I still can't resolve this. My code is :

```
<div class="container5">
    <h1 class="header5">Skill Kami</h1>
    <hr width="150px" color="#2EA2DB" style="position: relative; top: 160px; left: 95px;">
    <p style="color: white; position: absolute; top: 180px; left: 100px; margin-right: 700px;">Tim Jasa Pembuatan Blog Anas terdiri dari 4 ahli professional yang sudah sangat berpengalaman dalam bidang mereka masing-masing. Ketika 4 professional tersebut bersatu maka akan tercipta sebuah pernyataan yang bisa menyimpulkan skill yang dimiliki oleh Jasa Pembuatan Blog Anas. Dan disebelah kanan adalah skill yang kami miliki hingga saat ini dan akan terus berkembang.</p>
    <div class="progress">
        <div class="progress-container">
            <div class="progress-bar tip" title="98%"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="progress-container">
            <div class="progress-bar tip" title="58%"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="progress-container">
            <div class="progress-bar tip" title="28%"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And below is my css :

```
.container5 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 450px;
    position: relative;
    top: -1400px;
    margin-top: 30px;
    background-image: url('1.png');
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}
.header5 {
    color: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    top: 80px;
    left: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 40px;
}
.progress {
    position: absolute;
    top: 180px;
    left: 800px;
}
.progress-container {
    height: 25px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: red;
    width: 460px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.progress-bar {
    height: 25px;
    width: 0px;
    text-align: right;
    line-height: 25px;
    background: white;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm trying to make it simple as possible. Just add more of your css.

```
<div class="progress-bar">
  <div><span>95%</span></div>
</div>

.progress-bar {
  height: 20px;
    background: #ccc;
    width: 250px;
}

.progress-bar div {
      height: 20px;
    background: blue;
    width: 95%;
}

.progress-bar div span {
  float: right;
    color: #fff;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/vandolphreyes29/dtss25av/4/

Also, I would recommend to use this framework. https://semantic-ui.com/modules/progress.html

Comment: Thanks for your help, now I can create the progress bar

Comment: Your welcome. Please don't forget the upvote. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

To create a proper progress bar with counter, you'll need to use [HTML5 Progress tag](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_progress.asp)

This tutorial on css-tricks will teach you how to do that: https://css-tricks.com/html5-progress-element/

```
<!-- basic html for progress bar -->
<progress max="100" value="0"></progress>
```

Comment: Ok, I will learn that first, I'll tell you again if I am success create the progress bar. Thank you before

Answer (score 0):

There is useful plugin for animated skills bars check it out
[Designify animated skills bar](http://designify.me/tutorials/show-off-your-skills-with-css-animated-bars/#.WQ7DkYhEm00).